# Jquery clearing value for multiple text fields at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 text fields in a form that I want to clear when clicking a div.

I gave each text field a class `class="1"` and am using this function to clear them.

```
$('#clear').click(function() {
    $(".1").val('');
});
```

This seems to work but I'm wondering if there's a better, standard way to do it.

Note: I don't want to clear the entire form.

Comment: can class/id names even start with digits?

Comment: @jnpcl: no, [not under html 4.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

Comment: There is the good old `<input type="reset" />` button...

Comment: Why use a jQuery approach, wben html supplies the `<input type="reset" value="button text" />` optoion?

Comment: I have mentioned that I don't want to clear the entire form. Just those 4 text fields. Reset button wouldn't be good. @jnpcl, I was just testing. It seems to work tho

Comment: @Cyber: Then you already found the best way :)

Comment: @Felix, thanks! I don't have a lot of jquery experience.. wasn't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from that being an invalid class name (pretty sure they can't start with a number), this should be fine.  I would however name the class in a more meaningful way.

Answer (score 2):

Just be clear you shouldn't have css names start with a number to conform to the standard.  But if you do manage to make that work you just might have to make your selector be slightly different and it should pick it up.

```
$("#clear").click(function() {
    $("input[class='1']").val("");
});
```

Comment: This is what I would do, just with a valid class name